# Jenkins build fails with error - Exit status of command '/var/../gradlew clean testStoreReleaseUnitTest assembleStoreRelease -p .' was 1 instead of 0

Tags: android, jenkins, exit, build-error

Getting **Console Output** of Jenkins build error as follow-

```
Exit status of command '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/inkMobile-Android_master-YOSIH6EBA55H3BHM...PT7KXE7D7U4DPW6Q/gradlew clean testStoreReleaseUnitTest assembleStoreRelease -p .' was 1 instead of 0.
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/inkMobile-Android_master-YOSIH6EBA5....PW6Q/C:\androidStudio\sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

I'm building my project on jenkins by clicking **Build Now**, but in second stage- **Build & Test**, error comes and build gets fail.

Can someone tell me what this error means?